# 404 error when using wordpress api - php works, python doesn't

Tags: python, php, wordpress

I am trying to use the wordpress API to make posts to my website.  I get a 404 error.  I asked a colleague to do the same, with the same credentials in PHP and that worked.

This is my Python code:

---

```
##IMPORT LIBRARIES
import requests
import base64
import json

url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
username = "username"
password = "**** **** **** **** **** ****" #This is the application password, set within wordpress
creds = username + ':' + password
cred_token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + cred_token.decode('utf-8')}

def do_post():
 post = {
  'title': 'I will scream if this does not work',
  'content': 'Hello, this content is published using WordPress Python Integration',
  'status': 'publish',
  'categories': '3',
  'tags': '',
  'date': '1999-12-05T11:00:00'
 }
 blog = requests.put(urlforpost + '/posts' , headers=header , json=post)
 print(blog)

def main():
 print(creds)
 print(cred_token)
 print(header)
 do_post()

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

This is his PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once("wp-load.php");
$auth = 'username:**** **** **** **** **** ****';
echo base64_encode( $auth );
$api_response = wp_remote_post( https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts, array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $auth ),
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'title'   => 'This is WordPress Python Integration Testing, but through php I guess',
        'status'  => 'publish',
        'content' => 'Hello, this content is published using WordPress Python Integration only its through php this time',
        'categories' => '1',
        'tags' => '',
        'date' => "2021-12-05T11:00:00"
    )
) );         
$body = json_decode( $api_response['body'] );
if( wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $api_response ) === 'Created' ) {
    echo "<div class='notice'>";                        
    echo 'The post ' . $body->title->rendered . ' has been created successfully';
    echo "</div>";
}else{
    echo "<div class='notice'>";
    echo wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $api_response );
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

---

For then life of me, I cannot figure out why his works and mine doesn't.

Any suggestions

Comment: When I copy, paste and run your code, I get an error message: 'urlforpost' is not defined. I then replaced this with url variable and I get 403 forbiden error. Maybe I did not supply the correct password.

Comment: According to your code, shouldn't `urlforpost + '/posts'` be just `url`? As Sikeh pointed out above, it doesn't seem that `urlforpost` has been defined anywhere.